# JQuery hide/show using mouseX percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is super simple and I'm close (ish.) I'm trying to toggle between 10 divs (showing only one at a time) based on the mouse's X position.

At the moment I've turned the mouse's X position into a percentage and am using it as a variable to show/hide an element based on how far across the cursor is, however i'm having trouble figuring out how to manage the 10 elements so only one shows at a time.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zn8zaoc/)

Thanks!

```
//Look at mouse
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    // Set a variable (perc) X mouse position in pixels divide by the browser size times by 100
    var perc = e.pageX / $(document).width() * 100;

    // If that perc is less than 20 and higher than 10
    if (perc > 20 && perc < 30) {
        // show flick span
        $('#flick1').show();
    }
    else {
        // or hide flick span
        $('#flick1').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    $spans = $("span[id^=flick]").removeClass("desc");
    var perc = Math.floor(e.pageX / $(document).width() * $spans.length);
    $spans.hide().eq(perc).show();
});
```

```css
.desc {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
    <span id="flick1">word 1</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick2">word 2</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick3">word 3</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick4">word 4</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick5">word 5</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick6">word 6</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick7">word 7</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick8">word 8</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick9">word 9</span>
    <span class="desc" id="flick10">word 10</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! – How would I turn off this script on mobile devices and just show another div? At the moment I'm using media queries but I don't think thats the most effective way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw the question was already solved, but I would still like to show my solution:

at this to your head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
//Look at mouse
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    //Set a variable (perc) X mouse position in pixels divide by the browser size times by 100
    var perc = e.pageX / $(document).width() * 100;
    //If that perc between 0 and 100 (whole page)
    if (perc > 0 && perc < 100) {
        //show flick span
        for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
           $('#flick'+i).hide();            
        }
        //round the number
        var nr = Math.round(perc/10);
        $('#flick'+nr).show();
        $('#flick'+nr).removeClass('desc');
    }
    else {
        //Hide all flicks
        for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
           $('#flick'+i).hide();            
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zn8zaoc/2/)

Happy coding :)